# JS- Traverse object

Tags: javascript, object, properties, traversal

I have a javascript object that has nested objects as properties. I would like to traverse this javascript object, to get a list of all the properties of every object inside the object.

I wrote a function to do this, but for some reason when I run the function I get an infinite loop of 0's. Does anyone know how the reason and solution for this issue?

```
var test = {a: {b: { c: 'value '}}}; 

var traverse = function(object){
  for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        console.log(property); 
        traverse(object[property])
    }else {
      console.log('None'); 
      break;
    }
  }
}
traverse(test);
```

Comment: `traverse("value")` -> `for (var property in object) { /*property === 0*/ if (object.hasOwnProperty("0") /* true */) { traverse("v") }` -> `traverse("v")` -> `for (var property in object) { /*property === 0*/ if (object.hasOwnProperty("0") /* true */) { traverse("v") }` -> ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a string at the end and this string is separated into a single characters with one index zero. From this string, the character at position zero is taken and the recursion is called again with a single character.

> ```
>  key          value           comment
> -----  -------------------  -----------
>   a    {
>            b: {
>                c: "value "
>            }
>        }
>
>   b    {
>            c: "value "
>        }
>
>   c    "value "
>
>   0    "v"
>   0    "v"
>   0    "v"                  and so on
> ```

This character has an index zero and so on.

To prevent such habit, you could check for onyl truthy values (prevent `null`) and type of objects to get traversed.

```js
var test = { a: { b: { c: 'value ' } } };

var traverse = function (object) {
    for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            console.log(property);
            if (object[property] && typeof object[property] === 'object') {
                traverse(object[property]);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('None');
        }
    }
}
traverse(test);
```